# Normalized Wavelet power spectrum

Tags: wavelet

I am analyzing the spectral components of a time series using the continuous wavelet transform following Torrence and Compo (1998). I would like to partition the signal variability or spectral power across different scales (e.g. 50% of the variability is in the scales X to Y).

As pointed out [here](http://paos.colorado.edu/research/wavelets/faq.html#bias) the global wavelet spectrum is a biased estimator of the power spectrum, so is there a way to plot the power spectrum in a normalized way, where I can compare the power at different frequencies?

Would it be correct to just reconstruct each scale range I am interested in and calculate the variance over time?

Answer (score 3):

I've used the [Liu-Liang-Weisberg paper](http://ocg6.marine.usf.edu/~liu/Papers/Liu_etal_2007_JAOT_wavelet.pdf) before, and it worked pretty well. There's some example [code on this page](http://ocg6.marine.usf.edu/~liu/wavelet_test_ElNino3_YLiu.m).

In short, they propose that squaring wavelet coefficients and dividing them by their respective scales normalizes the spectrum. The paper provides proof and motivation.

Comment: Thanks, this allows normalizing the power spectrum. Any contributions on variance partitioning from the Wavelet transform will be welcome.